# Verify that a string is a comma separated list SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When imported some data from client I must verify that a column is comma-separated and that all the values between commas are letters. Is there a function I can use?

Example

```
DECLARE @TestStringGood varchar(255), @TestStringBad varchar(255)

SET @TestStringGood = '1,3,4,8,9'
SET @TestStringBad = '1,aa,33,1,b' or '4344343'
```

How do I validate the above 2 strings?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean here by letters?? single numerics separated by comma or single alphabets separated by comma??

Comment: Hi I mean The string cannot have letters at all,but can have numbers provided they are comma separated

Comment: is `1,22,3` a good or a bad string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that some of the numbers can contain multiple digits, and that the string shouldn't start or end with commas and that no "empty" values should exist, I'd actually make each of those tests explicit:

```
@StringVariable NOT LIKE '%[^0-9,]%' AND
@StringVariable NOT LIKE ',%' AND
@StringVariable NOT LIKE '%,' AND
@StringVariable NOT LIKE '%,,%'
```

The first of these tests is "the string does *not* contain any character *not* found in the sequence 0-9 or ,".

---

There may be a way to combine some of these checks but I don't immediately see it. I'd also suggest investigating whether you could replace this input entirely with e.g. a table-valued parameter, which is a type *designed* for storing multiple values, unlike this string, and would also be strongly typed to e.g. contain `int` values.

Comment: Thanks for your help.That gave me something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

there is no the kind of function you want in sql server.

you should use the idea of a delimiter, which in your case is going to be the comma

if there is no delimiter in your string at all, it is the "@TestStringBad" case. and if there is. you're going to check each of them if they are numeric or not with the function ISNUMERIC. which returns 1 if the value is a number..

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` also returns 1 for `£` and `.`. Do you really think of those as numbers?

Comment: if you don't want those symbols either, then using char codes might be a solution

Comment: char codes for numbers for 0-9 are from CHAR(48)-0 up to CHAR(57)-9

Comment: I'm just really pointing out that `ISNUMERIC` is rarely, if ever, the right solution to a problem. In fact, I'd go so far as to say that anytime I encounter `ISNUMERIC` in code, I'm going to find a bug where someone's not realised the true awfulness of what that function actually answers.